# Sorting array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

firstArray

```
 [
 {
  type:"one",
  ID : "1",
  isValid:"true"
 },
 {
  type:"two",
  ID : "2",
  isValid:"false"
 },
 {
  type:"two",
  ID : "3",
  isValid:"true"
 }
]
```

I have an array of object like the above one. i have to take all the valid objects. By iterating them,I ll get an array of objects which contains only valid objects. I have done this part successfully.

```
 var valid_types = $.grep(firstArray, function(v)
  { 
         return v.isValid=== "true";
  });

 ["two","five","three","one","four"]
```

I have another array which specifies the sorting order. How do i sort the resulting array based on the type? I am confused a bit. Any suggestions? I have to sort valid_types based on type

Doubts:
   Resulting array can have same type of valid objects and it may not have all the types specified in the sorting order. How to handle this?

DESIRED ARRAY:

```
[
  {
  type:"two",
  ID : "3",
  isValid:"true"
  },
  {
  type:"one",
  ID : "1",
  isValid:"true"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please tell me the reason for downvoting

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect that the person who did (who should have explained why in a comment) was concerned about the lack of code in your question.

Comment: @Pointy thanks. I don't know how to sort it shortly. That's why i posted here. I have done half of my part. What code are you expecting still?

Comment: Or maybe because your object is not valid

Comment: What is the desired resulting array?

Comment: Desired resulting array should be in the order which is based on the second array i provided. Sort is not based on ID. It's based on String 'type'

Comment: You can use `.filter()` to create an array with valid objects, and then you just need to call `.sort()` on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .sort() function to sort your array with a custom function.

```
var order =  ["two","five","three","one","four"];
var data = [{
        type:"one",
        ID : "1",
        isValid:"true"
    },
    {
        type:"two",
        ID : "2",
        isValid:"false"
    },
    {
        type:"two",
        ID : "3",
        isValid:"true"
    }
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return order.indexOf(a.type) - order.indexOf(b.type);
});
//use your sorted array
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution, but it's not really good to do it like this.

First i add a property to each object with the int value of the type. After that you can sort them by that property.

```js
var arr = [
 {
  type:"two",
  ID : "2",
  isValid:"false"
 },
 {
  type:"one",
  ID : "1",
  isValid:"true"
 },
 {
  type:"two",
  ID : "3",
  isValid:"true"
 }
];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  switch(arr[i].type){
    case "one":
      arr[i].typeNum = 1;
      break;
    case "two":
      arr[i].typeNum = 2;
      break;
  }
}

arr.sort(function(a, b){
 return a.typeNum-b.typeNum
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @user3801433 Sorry, but i think that i have what you want. They are sorted by the type now.

Comment: I shouldn't add any numbers in he array. That's why i posted andreas

Comment: Ok, than you have to go with the other solution from @Benjamin P.